# GCM Notifications are not working on some wifi connection

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am creating an application with the GCM push notifications (Android) but I am getting a problem actually when I am using the application on my company wifi network it is working perfectly but on same hand it is not working on my home wifi network.

Answer (score 1):

You got to open port 5258,29,30. And in other hands, it has to be on same network (if the server is only deployed on your company networks.. it can't works at your home).